# Email 2 or more Excel Workbooks with Vba

Tags: email, vba, excel

I cannot figure out how to send more than 1 workbook for the life of me!
I know a couple different ways to email 1 workbook, I place them here.

```
Sub SendActiveWorkbook()
                ActiveWorkbook.SendMail _
    Recipients:=Array("MyEmail@123.com", "AnotherEmail@123.com"), _
    Subject:="Write subject here"                 
End Sub
```

And

```
Sub RouteActiveWorkbook()   
    With ActiveWorkbook
           .HasRoutingSlip = True
               With .RoutingSlip
                    .Delivery = xlAllAtOnce
                    .Recipients = Array("MyEmail@123.com", "AnotherEmail@123.com")
                    .Subject = "CSAM Lux BIEO and BCF breakdown"
                    .Message = "Attached are the breakdowns as of " & Date
               End With
            .Route
     End With
End Sub
```

I seem to be only able to send 1 workbook in a given email. (it will not solve my problem to make my 2 workbooks into 1 workbook). Anyone had any success with sending more than 1 workbook in an email?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a basic example to send an email with more than 1 attachment. Please amend as applicable for realistic scenario. Also I have not taken care of error handling in the below example.

**TRIED AND TESTED**

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim MyFileList(1) As String
    Dim i As Long
    
    '~~> Change/Add the file names here
    MyFileList(0) = "C:\Sample1.xlsm"
    MyFileList(1) = "C:\Sample2.xlsm"
    
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
    
    With OutMail
        .To = "MyEmail@123.com"
        .Subject = "Example for attaching 2 files"
        .Body = "Hi Ommit :)"
                
        For i = LBound(MyFileList) To UBound(MyFileList)
            .Attachments.Add MyFileList(i)
        Next i
                
        .Display
    End With
End Sub
```